# XSLT XPath, Need to change node value to based on number value of a sibling node

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am trying to change a node value to one of two different things by checking to see if the the following node contains an odd or even number.

This is the source XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FILE>
<CLAIM>
<PERSON>
<PROVIDER>
<HEADER>
<FLAG>PPON</FLAG>
<IDNO>11612</IDNO>
</HEADER>
</PROVIDER>
</PERSON>
</CLAIM>
</FILE>
```

And the XSLT I'm trying is:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' ?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output 
        method="xml" 
        version="1.0" 
        encoding="UTF-8" 
        indent="yes" 
        omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="FLAG/node()">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="number(../IDNO) mod 2 = 0">EVEN</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>ODD</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And what I want to the output to be is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FILE>
<CLAIM>
<PERSON>
<PROVIDER>
<HEADER>
<FLAG>EVEN</FLAG>
<IDNO>11612</IDNO>
</HEADER>
</PROVIDER>
</PERSON>
</CLAIM>
</FILE>
```

I know I'm not getting the IDNO in my when test because my code gives me ODD all the time, also while debugging I tried putting the value of the when test into FLAG and I get NaN. But I can't come up with the correct syntax to get the IDNO into the test.

And yes, I'm new to XSLT, so maybe this is a dumb question, but I've tried many different things and searched this site and others for the answer with no luck.

Thanks in advance for your help.

DWL

Comment: I am assuming it is a typo in your question, but your XSLT is looking for elements in the namespace "http://www.mycompany.com/services/core/file", but there is no sign of any namespaces in your XML, so as it is stands `a:FLAG` would not match anything!

Comment: Thanks. I edited the question (and my "real" XML and XSLT) and removed the namespace references. But I still get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You current template matches on a child of **FLAG**

```
<xsl:template match="FLAG/node()">
```

Now, when you use `..` this is looking for the parent, so `..` will match **FLAG** in this context, and so `../IDNO` is looking for a child of **FLAG** called **IDNO**, which does not exist.

You need to go one more level up. Try this instead

```
<xsl:template match="FLAG/text()">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="number(../../IDNO) mod 2 = 0">EVEN</xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>ODD</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick. Special thanks for the explanation, not just the answer.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to not check the axis of the node, but rather the node itself:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:a="http://www.mycompany.com/services/core/file" exclude-result-prefixes="a">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="IDNO">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="number(.) mod 2 = 0">EVEN</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>ODD</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```